# An uncaught error when trying to update the result of a python script using brython

Tags: brython

I'm new to brython. I got an `uncaught error` when trying to update the running result of a python script to my page using brython.

```
Uncaught Error
    at Object._b_.AttributeError.$factory (eval at $make_exc (brython.js:7017), <anonymous>:31:340)
    at attr_error (brython.js:6184)
    at Object.$B.$getattr (brython.js:6269)
    at CallWikifier0 (eval at $B.loop (brython.js:4702), <anonymous>:34:66)
    at eval (eval at $B.loop (brython.js:4702), <anonymous>:111:153)
    at $B.loop (brython.js:4702)
    at $B.inImported (brython.js:4696)
    at $B.loop (brython.js:4708)
    at $B.inImported (brython.js:4696)
    at $B.loop (brython.js:4708)
```

Here my page

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
<script src="/brython-3.7.0rc1/www/src/brython.js"></script>
<script src="/brython-3.7.0rc1/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="brython()">
<script type="text/python" src="vttToWiki.py"></script>
<div class="wrap">title</div>
<p id="content-title"></p>
<div class="wrap">subtitle</div>
<div id="content-subtitle" class="content-div">
<p id="message" font-color=white>loading...</p> 
</div>
<button id="mybutton">click!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Here my python script. This is script contact with `http://www.wikifier.org/annotate-article`, which is a website for semantic annotation. Given a text, the function `CallWikifier` got the annotation result and wiki url accordingly.

```
import sys, json, urllib.parse, urllib.request
from browser import alert, document, html

element = document.getElementById("content-title")
def CallWikifier(text, lang="en", threshold=0.8):
    # Prepare the URL.
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode([
        ("text", text), ("lang", lang),
        ("userKey", "trnwaxlgwchfgxqqnlfltzdfihiakr"),
        ("pageRankSqThreshold", "%g" % threshold), ("applyPageRankSqThreshold", "true"),
        ("nTopDfValuesToIgnore", "200"), ("nWordsToIgnoreFromList", "200"),
        ("wikiDataClasses", "true"), ("wikiDataClassIds", "false"),
        ("support", "true"), ("ranges", "false"),
        ("includeCosines", "false"), ("maxMentionEntropy", "3")
        ])
    url = "http://www.wikifier.org/annotate-article"
    # Call the Wikifier and read the response.
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data.encode("utf8"), method="POST")
    with urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout = 60) as f:
        response = f.read()
        response = json.loads(response.decode("utf8"))
    # Save the response as a JSON file
    with open("record.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(response, f)
    # update the annotations.
    for annotation in response["annotations"]:
        alert(annotation["title"])
        elt = document.createElement("B")
        txt = document.createTextNode(f"{annotation}\n")
        elt.appendChild(txt)
        element.appendChild(elt)

document["mybutton"].addEventListener("click", CallWikifier("foreign minister has said Damascus is ready " +"to offer a prisoner exchange with rebels.")
```

If you have any idea about that please let me know. Thank you for advice!

Comment: I have narrow down the error to line "req = request.Request(url, data=data.encode("utf8"), method="POST")", it seems that it is an import error. "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Request'"

Comment: I find a useful problem for me. [link](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/issues/308) But I still got the AttributeError as following:`Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Request'`

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460131/import-psaw-brython